# A PDE with mixed derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

How should one go about solving an equation of the form

$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} + x \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = y$$

Do I need to use characteristics, or integrate first?

Comment: First, perform integration w.r.t. $y$ and then proceed.

Comment: So that should give $u_y +xy = y^3/3$?

Comment: i think you should get (after integrating with respect to $y$) $u_x+xu=y^2/2+g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is some function of $x$ determined from initial/boundary conditions

Answer (score 3):

A first integration w.r.t $y$ would give
$$
u_x+xu=\frac{y^2}{2}+f(x),
$$
where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$. Now we multiply the sides of the equation in $\exp(\frac{x^2}{2})$ to get
$$
[\exp(\frac{x^2}{2})u]_x=\exp(\frac{x^2}{2})u_x+x\exp(\frac{x^2}{2})u=\frac{y^2}{2}\exp(\frac{x^2}{2})+f(x)\exp(\frac{x^2}{2})
$$where another integration (this time w.r.t. $x$) yields
$$
\exp(\frac{x^2}{2})u=\frac{y^2}{2}[\int \exp(\frac{x^2}{2})dx+g(y)]+h(y)+\int f(x)\exp(\frac{x^2}{2})dx,
$$
together giving
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{2}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})\int \exp(\frac{x^2}{2})dx+h_1(y)\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})+h_2(x)
$$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear why we need $\exp(x^2/2)$